# Delete WooCommerce Item From Cart

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart

Looking to remove an item from a custom mobile cart in Woocommerce.

```
<div class="mobile-cart-pop-out-menu-items">
    <ul>
      <?php global $woocommerce;
      $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
      foreach($items as $item => $values) { ?>
            <? $_product = $values['data']->post; ?>
            <li>
              <h3>X</h3>
              <h4><? echo $_product->post_title; ?></h4>
              <h5><? $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);echo "£".$price; ?></h5>
            </li>
      <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div><!--ends items-->
```

I want to be able to click the X to remove that item from the cart, but cant find any code snippets or help to work out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The woocommerce template located in templates/cart/cart.php shows you how to do this.

```
<?php
    // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine
    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(
        '<a href="%s" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s"><i class="pe-7s-close"></i></a>',
        esc_url( wc_get_cart_remove_url( YOURCARTITEMID ) ),
        __( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
        esc_attr( $values['product_id'] ),
        esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
    ), YOURCARTITEMID );
?>
```

Is the code you need to generate the delete from cart link.